# How to add an older version of syntaxhighlighter

Tags: javascript, css, syntax-highlighting, blogger, syntaxhighlighter

I have added the latest version of Syntax Highlighter (http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) for my site and it looks like this

[image]

I have seen in some blogs a Syntax Highlighter version with printer and copy buttons as shown in the following image. I want to add code stubs in my site also like this

[image]

Can I add this version for my site ?? 
If I can how to do this? or how to change the new version ?

Comment: Are you sure syntax highlighter is what they use?

Comment: yes it is an older version of syntaxhighlighter

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an older version, you need to [turn on the toolbar](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/configuration/). It's off by default.

Comment: I also like  to change the fonts and colors of the syntaxhighlighter as second image how to do this ??

Comment: You need to use a theme. It's also explained in the documentation I linked to!

Comment: there isn't any theme looking same as shown in my second image

Comment: they're just CSS, dude. I can't fathom why you'd need a syntax highlighter but not know how to whip up a stylesheet.

Comment: Keep it calm here. No arguing